# Checkout project from Google code using Ant error

Tags: svn, ant, google-code, svnant

```
    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" />   
    ...
    <target name="main" depends="clean">
        <svn javahl='false' >
            <checkout url="${gae_api_source}" destPath="${localDir}" recurse="true">
            </checkout>
        </svn>
    </target>
```

I use the above SVN ant script to checkout GAE source, but lead to error:

```
[svn] <Checkout> started ...
      [svn] svn: connection refused by the server
      [svn] svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api'
      [svn] svn: connection refused by the server
      [svn] svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api'
      [svn] Connection timed out: connect
      [svn] <Checkout> failed !
```

I use SvnAnt 1.3.1, Ant 1.8.1, When i checkout from the TortoiseSvn or Eclipse it works just fine, Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried your sample and it works for me in the same configuration (SvnAnt 1.3.1, Ant 1.8.1)

Comment: <property name="gae_api_source" value="http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/"/>  <path id="svnant.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${svnant.lib.dir}">     
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path><typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" 
          classpathref="svnant.classpath"/>

Comment: May be it is proxy or firewall issue. Did you check your script with another svn url?

Comment: Yes! it is the proxy issue, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a proxy problem(i didn't set), Thank Alex K for his wonderful reminder.